# Is it possible to get shell at the end of debian installation but before rebooting?

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I want to run some post-installation commands. The installer offers only reboot option. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: GUI installation or command line? Can you drop to a tty with Ctrl+Alt+F1?

Comment: It offers GUI installation and "another" one. I'm trying "another" option. Thank you, I'll try that

Comment: Even in a text based installation, you might be able to get a shell with "Alt+F2" or F3 or something. I'm not sure if the multiuser environment is set up at the end of installation but it might be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a console provided during installation on [the second VT](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch06s03.html#shell) (and the third); you can access it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> for the third one). The installer is on the first VT (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>) and the detailed installer logs are on the fourth.

You'll also find a "shell" option in the main installer menu; this will open a shell in the first VT, which you need to exit to return to the installer.

Answer (score 2):

The way I have done this when customising Ubuntu installs is to place a script (here called `installer-late-command`) into the root of the CDROM, and arrange for it to be run in the target environment.  I expect that this approach, or something similar will work in plain Debian.  I use this line in my seed file:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string cp /cdrom/installer-late-command /target/tmp; in-target /tmp/installer-late-command
```

(`in-target` is a script that's on the CDROM, which chroots into the target to run programs)

My script is not interactive; I have no idea whether this will work for something which is.  Also, I use a text console installer, not a graphical one, in case that makes a difference.

Of course, for interactive work, just changing to a different virtual terminal should be sufficient.  I think you're provided with three (and can view logs on the fourth).